# how to get a card reader name on command line

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, pcsc

I am writing code to communicate with a smart card on Windows 7. The sample code that accompanies the card is developed on the `linux` environment. I have installed Mingw and Msys the Linux minimal system.

The correct command to get the reader name on the linux environment is `pcsc_scan`. But using this command is neither recognised by the Msys command prompt nor the Windows console.

I know that Winscard can be used to list all readers. But is there a way to get the `pcsc_scan`  command to work on Windows. Or is there a command for that on the Windows environment? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Windows 7 has some good SmartCard access functionality. Have a look at the Windows Biometric Framework. If you are interested in a C# implementation I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ubuntu man page for pcsc_scan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pcsc_scan.1.html):

> pcsc_scan  is  a  program  that  regularly  scans  every  PC/SC
>   readers
>          connected to the host

Key idea: *pcsc_scan is a program* and is compiled for linux and will therefore not run on Windows. (It's also either not a part of Mingw or Msys min or your path is incorrect. To double check, run a disk search for a file named pcsc_scan.)

If you can't locate pcsc_scan in Mingw or Msys then you will need either an equivalent of pcsc_scan for Windows or some other utility like [this Java Smart Card Explorer](http://www.winsite.com/Home-Education/Science/Java-Smart-Card-Explorer/) which happens to actually be cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Smart Card explorer provides a comprehensive user interface. However, the connection to the card still fails with the "connect() fail" error and that reported on command line is "SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH". I think it is the real problem for the connection. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the package pcsc-sdkxxx can give you some information.
Look at www.springcard.com/en/download/sdks

In the package the program pcscmon have a similar functionality.